# Powerpoint VBA save slides with keyword as JPEG

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Currently i have a macro on PowerPoint that finds keyword(s) on a PowerPoint file and saves the slides that contains the keywords as JPEG files. However, I noticed that since the code runs through each shape, it saves the file before every keyword in a slide is found, this thus created many JPEG files with the same slide page but with one keyword highlighted every time, is there any way to make the macro print a slide after every keyword is found on that slide?

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fgdg()

Dim sImagePath As String
Dim sImageName As String
Dim lScaleWidth As Long '* Scale Width
Dim lScaleHeight As Long '* Scale Height
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim txtRng As TextRange, rngFound As TextRange
Dim i As Long, n As Long
Dim TargetList
On Error GoTo Err_ImageSave
'~~>  EDIT THE ITEMS IN THE ARRAY() TO FIND DESIRED WORD(S)
TargetList = Array("doodle")

'~~> Loop through each slide
For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    '~~> Loop through each shape
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        '~~> Check if it has text
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            sImagePath = "D:/"
            For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
                '~~> Find the text
                Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i))

                '~~~> If found
                Do While Not rngFound Is Nothing
                    '~~> Set the marker so that the next find starts from here
                    n = rngFound.Start + 1
                    '~~> Change attributes
                    With rngFound.Font
                        .Bold = msoTrue
                        .Underline = msoTrue
                        .Italic = msoTrue
                        .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        sImageName = rngFound.Start & ".jpg"
                        sld.Export sImagePath & sImageName, "JPG"
                        '~~> Find Next instance
                        Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i), n)

                    End With
                Loop
            Next
        End If
    Next
Next
Err_ImageSave:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the Export line outside of the Do While if you want to do that. In the modified code below, I added a flag which is set if at least one keyword is found and then once the TargetList has been fully checked, if the flag is true, the slide is exported in the format "Slide X.jpg". The code is untested.

```
Option Explicit

Sub fgdg()

Dim sImagePath As String
Dim sImageName As String
Dim lScaleWidth As Long '* Scale Width
Dim lScaleHeight As Long '* Scale Height
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape
Dim txtRng As TextRange, rngFound As TextRange
Dim i As Long, n As Long
Dim TargetList
Dim bFound As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_ImageSave
'~~>  EDIT THE ITEMS IN THE ARRAY() TO FIND DESIRED WORD(S)
TargetList = Array("doodle")

'~~> Loop through each slide
For Each sld In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    '~~> Reset the found flag
    bFound = False
    '~~> Loop through each shape
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        '~~> Check if it has text
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            Set txtRng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
            sImagePath = "D:/"
            For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)
                '~~> Find the text
                Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i))

                '~~~> If found
                Do While Not rngFound Is Nothing
                    '~~> Set a flag to indicate that at least one keyword has been found
                    bFound = True
                    '~~> Set the marker so that the next find starts from here
                    n = rngFound.Start + 1
                    '~~> Change attributes
                    With rngFound.Font
                        .Bold = msoTrue
                        .Underline = msoTrue
                        .Italic = msoTrue
                        .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        'sImageName = rngFound.Start & ".jpg"
                        'sld.Export sImagePath & sImageName, "JPG"
                        '~~> Find Next instance
                        Set rngFound = txtRng.Find(TargetList(i), n)
                    End With
                Loop
            Next
            '~~> If at least one keyword was found, export the slide
            If bFound Then sld.Export sImagePath & "Slide " & sld.SlideIndex, "JPG"
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Err_ImageSave:
        If Err <> 0 Then
            MsgBox Err.Description
        End If
    End Sub